# Plotting In MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, ode

I have a code that I would like to add an additional plot inside. I want to plot the relative error of two of my functions. I am unsure where in the loop to place this so that it doesn't give me an error message and plots all three cases as single graphs. Also, my relative error code may have some mistakes, which is what may be causing the problem.

This is the relative error code:

```
rel_error = (y_exact1 - Y(:,2)')./y_exact; %relative error 
figure()
plot(T,rel_error,'r')
```

This is the function I need to add it into

```
function ivp1()
clear;clc;close all;
t=linspace(0,2.5);
K=[.02 .1 1.5];

for i=1:3
k =K(i);

[T,Y] = ode45(@prblm1_fun,t,0); %Solving for the approximate solution    to the IVP 

figure()
plot(T,Y)
hold on 

y_exact1 = 1/(k^2+pi^2)*(pi*exp(k*t)-pi*cos(pi*t)-k*sin(pi*t));
y_exact2 = 1/(2*k)*(exp(k*(t-1))-1) + pi/(k^2+pi^2)*(exp(k*t) + exp(k* (t-1)));
y_exact3 = 1/2/k*(exp(k*(t-1))-exp(k*(t-2))) + pi/(k^2+pi^2)*(exp(k*t) + exp(k*(t-1))) + 1/2/(k-1)*(exp(k*(t-2)) - exp(t-2));

for i=1:length(t)

if t(i)<1
plot(t(i),y_exact1(i),'mo')
hold on 

elseif t(i)<2
plot(t(i),y_exact2(i),'mo')
hold on

else
plot (t(i),y_exact3(i),'mo')
hold on

end
end
end
function dy= prblm1_fun(t,y) %This is the function of the IVP for     varying values of t 
dy = zeros(1,1); 
if t < 1
dy(1)= y(1)*k + sin(pi*t);
elseif t < 2
dy(1)= y(1)*k + 0.5;
else
dy(1)= y(1)*k + exp(t-2)/2;
end
end
end
```

This is the desired result for one of the k values:
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Which error message are you getting? Could you attach a diagram of the desired result (even something crude in _paint_ would do)?

Comment: @Dev-iL I just added images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two erroneous places:

1) `Y` is a `100x1` matrix from the result of `ode45`. Trying to access `Y(:,2)` leads into a out-of-boundary error.

2) `y_exact` is not defined. You only have `y_exact1`, `y_exact2` and `y_exact3`.

Sample code:

```
function ivp1()
clear;clc;close all;
t=linspace(0,2.5);
K=[.02 .1 1.5];

for i=1:3
    k =K(i);

    [T,Y] = ode45(@prblm1_fun,t,0); %Solving for the approximate solution    to the IVP

    figure()
    plot(T,Y)
    hold on

    y_exact1 = 1/(k^2+pi^2)*(pi*exp(k*t)-pi*cos(pi*t)-k*sin(pi*t));
    y_exact2 = 1/(2*k)*(exp(k*(t-1))-1) + pi/(k^2+pi^2)*(exp(k*t) + exp(k* (t-1)));
    y_exact3 = 1/2/k*(exp(k*(t-1))-exp(k*(t-2))) + pi/(k^2+pi^2)*(exp(k*t) + exp(k*(t-1))) + 1/2/(k-1)*(exp(k*(t-2)) - exp(t-2));

    for j=1:length(t)
        if t(j)<1
            y_exact = y_exact1(j);
        elseif t(j)<2
            y_exact = y_exact2(j);
        else
            y_exact = y_exact3(j);
        end
        plot(t(j),y_exact,'mo')
    end
    rel_error = (y_exact1 - Y(:,1)')./y_exact; %relative error
    plot(T,rel_error,'r')
end
function dy= prblm1_fun(t,y) %This is the function of the IVP for     varying values of t
dy = zeros(1,1);
if t < 1
    dy(1)= y(1)*k + sin(pi*t);
elseif t < 2
    dy(1)= y(1)*k + 0.5;
else
    dy(1)= y(1)*k + exp(t-2)/2;
end
end
end
```

Sample output:

[image]